# Codeigniter - Ajax How to Display data to HTML Page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, cordova

Currently I am developing a Hybrid mobile application using phonegap. And I use PHP for making my app Dynamic (in Back end). I use below steps for my app development:

- First i Create HTML Page and Give id to Div Tag for display Data
- After Add Jquery File in HTML Page.

  `$(document).ready(function() {
          GolbalURL = $.session.get('URL');
          $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: GolbalURL+"ftp.php",

                  dataType: "html",

                  success: function(response){

                          $("#divprofile").html(response); 
                  }
          });
  });`
- After that I create one php file Add My Connection Data, Loops and other Dynamic PHP code in that file.
- This Working With Phonegap When I run on Emulator even on Browser.

But my problem is that, my existing website is in Codeigniter and for any code level change in Codeigniter requires changes in phonegap files as well.

Is there any way that I can use Codeigniter's output in my app's HTML like I use PHP files output in my HTML page via AJAX.

Thanks in Advanced.

**Edit**
No Iframe

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, 
you want to load a complete HTML web page on your application. if so, just install 
`InAppBrowser Plugin` https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html
and read the documentation

Comment: can that plugin allow me input from app ?

Comment: it will allow you to open a web page as if you are opening it from the smartphone native browser. You can test your web page from the android/ios browser "smartphone or (s)emulator", if it is running well, so use this plugin.

Comment: No, I don't want like that. I want json or other output from codeigniter page to my html page. I can do that with core php using ajax

Comment: well, using json is the most simple way to load contents into your mobile app. you can use jquary library to parse json and load the conten into your page. see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Yes, How can I do it with Codeigniter ? I can do with core php but codeigniter new for me, And If I get Output, How can I get value from user (Input)? is there any example on that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe to display your codeigniter webpage.

Comment: Thanks, but No Iframe